# How to commit changes to Git repository anonymously

Tags: git, git-commit

I have an empty git repository (hosted on GitHub or wherever).

I want to commit my changes to it *anonymously* like the below picture. How should I setup my git configuration (preferably project specific config) to achieve that?

[image: below picture]

Thanks

PS: In case you're asking *But why?*, check out the conferences [Double-Blind review process](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/social-science-and-medicine/policies/double-blind-peer-review-guidelines).

Comment: Curious, what's the reason for this?

Comment: @evolutionxbox [Double-Blind Peer Review Guidelines](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/social-science-and-medicine/policies/double-blind-peer-review-guidelines)

Comment: First I've heard of this. Thanks, I'll have a read.

Comment: For the record, GitHub counts the number of contributors based on [this set of conditions](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#contributions-that-are-counted)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From inside your local git repository;

```
git config user.name 'Anonymous'
git config user.email '<>'
```